# Can I merge two class in two java file into one?

Tags: android

The following code works well, but I think it is too complex.

**SmsBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public SmsBroadcastReceiver(){
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {

            PublicPar.myContext=context;            
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);               
                MSms myMSms=new MSms();     
                Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context,SmsInternetServer.class); 
                HandleSMS.SetIntentOrGetFromIntent(msgIntent, myMSms, true);
                context.startService(msgIntent);
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

**SmsInternetServer.java**

```
public class SmsInternetServer extends IntentService {

    public SmsInternetServer() {
        super("SmsInternetServer");     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HandleSMS.HandleReceivedSMS(intent);        
    }

}
```

so I merge the two class in two java file into one, is it OK? and is there more simple way to simplify code? such as anonymous class.

**SmsBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public SmsBroadcastReceiver(){
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {

            PublicPar.myContext=context;            
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);               
                MSms myMSms=new MSms();     
                Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context,SmsInternetServer.class); 
                HandleSMS.SetIntentOrGetFromIntent(msgIntent, myMSms, true);
                context.startService(msgIntent);
            }
        } 
    }

       //inner class
       class SmsInternetServer extends IntentService {

       public SmsInternetServer() {
        super("SmsInternetServer");     
       }

       @Override
       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HandleSMS.HandleReceivedSMS(intent);        
       }

       }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define as many class as you want in one java file .only restriction is you can have a single public class per file.
In your case also you could have defined SMSInternet server outside the SmsBroadcastReceiver . There is no need to define it as inner class

Comment: Thanks! Can inner class work? and can I define anonymous class to simplify code?

Comment: yes inner class would work.. but it will complicate referring to SmsinternetServer class from some other external class.because you will have to get object of outer class then you can get inner class object from outerclass object. Not sure about Anonymous classes if it woukd reduce complexities or not

Comment: Thanks!
But In AndroidManifest.xml, I need register receiver and service, if only have a single public class per file, will it cause error if I merge two class into one file?

        <receiver android:name="bll.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>              
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <service android:name="bll.SmsInternetServer"></service>